# Condition existence check in Azure : deny Policy

Tags: json, azure, azure-storage, azure-policy

Is it possible to create a policy definition to deny creation based on existence logic. For example - I want to deny storage blob or file share creation if EnableHttpsTrafficOnly is set to false on storage account. Please note , this policy should deny only creation of blob or share resources and not storage account creation.

Using below policy  but it did not work

````
"allOf": [
{
"not": {
"field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/supportsHttpsTrafficOnly",
"equals": "true"
}
},
{
"allOf": [
{
"source": "action",
"like": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares/*"
},
{
"field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares/enabledProtocols",
"equals": "SMB"
}
]
}
]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

For the question -

> Is it possible to create a policy definition to deny creation based on existence logic ?

The answer would be **yes**, you can create policy definitions based on the existence logic by using the **custom policy definitions**. Where you first determine the resource properties and apply conditions to set the effect to use.

I tried to reproduce what you are trying to do using the below policy definition but it was also not successful.

```js
{  
    "mode": "All",  
    "policyRule": {  
        "if": {  
            "allOf": [  
                {  
                    "field": "type",  
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices"  
                },  
                {         
                    "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/supportsHttpsTrafficOnly",
                    "notEquals": "true"
                }
            ]  
        },  
        "then": {  
            "effect": "deny"  
        }  
    },  
    "parameters": {}  
}
```

So I don't think we can deny storage blob or file share creation based on supportsHttpsTrafficOnly. But as supportsHttpsTrafficOnly is one of the [StorageAccountPropertiesCreateParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts?tabs=bicep#storageaccountpropertiescreateparameters), we can set deny creation policy on storage account as shown in the below code snippet.

```js
{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
        },
        {
            "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/supportsHttpsTrafficOnly",
            "notEquals": "true"
        }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
    }
}
```

I would suggest to read the [Create a custom policy definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition) and [Walkthrough using Azure Policy to audit and enforce compliance](https://azuredays.com/2020/07/09/walkthrough-using-azure-policy-to-audit-and-enforce-compliance/) document for more information.